# In Oracle SELECT query, how do you change the description for a particular entry?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a field in my table that provides description for vehicles (Cars, Trucks, Vans, etc.). Unfortunately the descriptions are not all uniform....

```
Example:
CAR#61
CAR # 124
CAR# 469
```

I need the data to read as follows:

`CAR#XXX` - No spaces, if the car is under the digits zero fill to make 3 digits. Example: `CAR#3` should read as `CAR#003`.

Also, I just need this for the cars.  Trucks, Vans, etc. shouldn't be changed at all.

Comment: It would be pretty easy to parse the strings, modify and concatenate as required; what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify database you use; Oracle SQL Developer is Oracle's tool which is capable of connecting to other databases, but - I presume you do use Oracle so - here's one option you might try.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from vehicles order by col;

COL
---------
CAR # 124
CAR# 469
CAR#61
TRUCK1
VAN  #2
```

Update only *cars*. How? `CAR#` is a *constant*, save some effort in extracting it. Then fetch any digits at the end of the string and left-pad that value with zeros, up to 3 characters in length.

```
SQL> update vehicles set
  2    col = 'CAR#' || lpad(regexp_substr(col, '\d+$'), 3, '0')
  3  where substr(col, 1, 3) = 'CAR';

3 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from vehicles order by col;

COL
---------
CAR#061
CAR#124
CAR#469
TRUCK1
VAN  #2

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks good, but assume I have 'read-only' access.  I dont have the capability of doing updates in our DB.  This is why I need to be able to do it in the select statement when pulling data.

Comment: You're welcome. What's preventing you from using that expression in an ordinary SELECT statement?